# EOF error while converting number sequence from list to tuple in one liner

Tags: python, tuples

```
print (tuple(list(input("enter sequence\n").strip(",")))
```

I tried to take a number sequence input, separate it by "," then convert it to list...then again convert it to tuples and print but,
it shows error: `unexpected EOF` while parsing!

Comment: `.strip(',')` doesn't separate a string based on `,`. You should be using `.split(',')` instead. The error you are getting is due to a missing `)` from the end

Comment: first of all break it into multiple lines. what input are you passing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
print (tuple(list(input("enter sequence\n").split(","))))
```

Also your code had mismatched parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try
    `print(tuple((raw_input("enter sequence\n").strip(',').split(','))))`

Your original code had two issues:

1. It was missing closing brackets so it would throw a SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2. If you want to separate the input by "," then you would use the split method. The strip method removes the given characters from the end of the string (so if you enter '1,2,4,5,' it would get rid of the comma on the right).
3. When you use the split method, it gives a list anyway, so you don't need to use the list function to make a list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.